# Xinetd Connection closed immediately

Tags: xinetd

We are migrating service from Solaris inetd to RHEL 7.x xinetd services. Following the configuration for service configured in xinetd

```
`service devb_tigre
 {
    socket_type     = stream
    protocol        = tcp
    wait            = no
    user            = root
    server          = /usr/bin/ksh
    server_args     = /opus/common/bin/tigred_run.sh devb
 }`
```

we have also added port/protocol entry in /etc/services file. port is 2060

After starting the xinetd service we see port is listing but if we telnet to it shows following result
`Trying 127.0.0.1... Connected to localhost. Escape character is '^]'. Connection closed by foreign host.`

contents of /opus/common/bin/tigred_run.sh are as follows

```
   `#!/bin/ksh
     . /opus/environments/$1/etc/opus.env >/dev/null 2>&1

      set +vx
      exec $TIGRE_BIN/tigred >/dev/null 2>&1`
```

please could anyone help on this

we should getting following result when telnet to it

`# telnet localhost 2060 Trying 127.0.0.1... Connected to localhost. Escape character is '^]'. *OK ~`